# How many child processes can a node.js cluster spawn on a 64bit Wintel PC?

Tags: windows, node.js, concurrency, 64-bit, process

I was running a concurrency test, and for brevity's sake, defined a process for each spoofed http request. It worked fine for up to 64 requests/processes, but folded on 65. I'm running Window 7 (64bit) on an I5 laptop, with 4GB of Ram.

Whilst running the test I had a Chrome open (with a handful of tabs), and I expect that the OS' common system processes would also have some effect, but I know too little about node.js at the lowest level to understand where the problem lies.

For example, one article suggest it's possible to run well over 8000 processes on a 2GB 64-bit Windows XP system:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx

But the 64 child process figure that I ran into was rather conspicuous.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this question is almost the same as "How many processes can you run on Windows 7 (64bit)?" which isn't really on topic for SO.

Comment: Interesting, but just curious, what are you trying to do exactly? The point of Node's model is supposed to be that a single Node process should be able to service a very large number of concurrent requests. You shouldn't need to spin up a new process for every concurrent request.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was just a lazy way to test a concurrent condition (in essence, I have each worker make a http request on startup, and return the status to the command line). So the discovery is serendipitous. :D @Dan D, I suppose I'm specifically interested in node.js processes, because the link I provided does contain a lot of info on the subject, but I wonder if node.js workers do anything specific in terms of memory usage/allocation per process. As Rohan suggested, it's an issue I can work around anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well node is asynchronous, there's no blocking, only by the current script and it can handle multiple connections perfectly, so that means on a high concurrency, it would use all of your CPU, but each process can only use one core, since Node is not threaded. So technically what is recommend to have is having as many processes as your cores, one core for each process. In that case, on a high concurrency the Node cluster would use all of the CPU. If you go more than that, you are wasting your RAM and putting extra work on your OS scheduler. Beside that each nodejs process have an startup time. So it is very expensive to create a nodejs process at run time.

From Node.JS docs:

> These child Nodes are still whole new instances of V8. Assume at least
> 30ms startup and 10mb memory for each new Node. That is, you cannot
> create many thousands of them.

Conclusion the best thing to do is to fork just as the number of your CPU cores, which is:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  // Worker processes have a http server.
  http.Server(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

We actually have a production server, doing that, which can take about 1000 concurrency, and  less than 10ms latency serving the hello world.

Comment: 100ms latency to serve a 'hello world'? I bag you to review that. I serve some cache out of Redis in 2ms from my dev-machine

Comment: Well I on my laptop I get it less than 10ms... The server performance is a bit low :(

Comment: What if I have two apps in the same server and these apps are clustered?

Imagine that I have a 4 cores cpu. Should I set for each app 2 cores or just use the maximum of cores in each apps?

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Given both apps have the same load and then 2 cores for each app will probably be more performant.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat Imagine that one app is a rest server and another is a server that crops images and handles uploads. What if I have a server for instance with 2 cores and I have 3 clustered apps in the same server? Do I have a big problem or do I just set each app with only one worker?

Comment: I cannot find someone that really knows how to handle this.

Comment: @LeandroCurioso You won't have big problems. The difference here is context switches and memory usage which you want to minimize. Safe bet in your case would be just have one worker per app. I'm assuming you server won't have much load and it'll be fine. Can an eye on the server loads, if you see one is using 100% CPU and others half that, that shows that one should have another worker.